# How to get the number of elements before the second last element in an array C#

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the int array below of n elements.

`1, 3, 4, 5, 7`. In this example the second last item is `5`. I want to get the number of elements in this array before the second last value. There are 3 elements before the second last element. I will store the result in an int variable to use later. We obviously take into account that the array will have more than two element all the time.

This array will have different size everytime.

How can I achieve this in the most simplistic way?

Comment: Assuming there are at least 2 elements: `int result = yourArray.Length - 2`? Or if there can be less than 2: `int result = Math.Max(0, yourArray.Length - 2)`

Comment: `int[] arr = ...; var num = arr.Length - 2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Range from C# 8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/building-c-8-0/#ranges-and-indices):

```
int[] arr = new int[]{1, 3, 4, 5, 7};
int[] newArr = arr.Length>=2 ? arr[..^2] : new int[0];
```

This will return all elements except the last 2, or an empty array if the lenght is less than 2. If it is guaranteed that the array will always have more than 2 elements, then you can simplify:

```
int[] newArr = arr[..^2];
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer will always be n-2, so a very quick solution is to use .Length property and to subtract 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested about the quantity of the numbers then `.Length-2` is the best way as it was stated by others as well.

If you are interested about the items as well without using C# 8 features then you can use `ArraySegment` ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1)).
It is really powerful, like you can reverse the items without affecting the underlying array.

```cs
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 5, 7 };
var segment = new ArraySegment<int>(arr, 0, arr.Length - 2);
var reversedSegment = segment.Reverse();  //ReverseIterator { 4, 3, 1 }
//arr >> int[5] { 1, 3, 4, 6, 7 }
```

Please bear in mind that the same is not true for `Span` ([2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1)).

```cs
var segment = new Span<int>(arr, 0, arr.Length - 2);
segment.Reverse();
//arr >> int[5] {4, 3, 1, 6, 7 }
```

There is a `ReadOnlySpan`, which does not allow to perform such operation as `Reverse`.
If you would need that then you have to manually iterate through that in a reversed order.